# Using storageState JSON of different users(e.g. admin/teamlead) with playwright and cucumber

Tags: node.js, typescript, cucumber, e2e-testing, playwright

I have a question about usage of storageState JSON for implementing parallel login of different users.
I would like to use this Tallyb repo https://github.com/Tallyb/cucumber-playwright,
where Cucumber is implemented with Playwright,to add a step to my existing test cases.
This step would allow me to log in as an admin using StorageState JSON,
eliminating the need to enter login details every time.
I also want to add another step to log in as a team lead using StorageState JSON,
and another one to log in as a user using StorageState JSON.

In this step, the following should occur:
If no JSON file for the desired user exists, it is created.
This is done by logging in with regular login details and storing the JSON.
If the necessary JSON file exists, it is used. If the JSON file is no longer valid,
it is recreated.

```
`/* eslint-disable indent */
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved
import { ICustomWorld } from '../support/custom-world';
import { Given } from '@cucumber/cucumber';
import { existsSync, readFileSync } from 'fs';

Given('the user logged in as an admin', async function (this: ICustomWorld) {
  const url = 'https://practice.automationtesting.in/my-account/';
  const authFile = 'playwright/.auth/admin.json';
  let storageState;

  // Check if the JSON file exists and is not empty
  if (existsSync(authFile)) {
    try {
      const fileContent = readFileSync(authFile, 'utf-8').trim();
      if (fileContent !== '') {
        storageState = JSON.parse(fileContent);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error reading or parsing the JSON file:', error);
    }
  }

  if (storageState) {
    // Restore state
    await this.setStorageState(authFile);
  } else {
    // Sign in
    await this.page?.goto(url);
    await this.loginPage?.login('xxxx@xxx.com', 'Test1234567');
    // Save the StorageState
    await this.saveStorageState(authFile);
    await this.page?.waitForLoadState('load');
  }
});`
```

// In Custom-world I have saveStorageState and setStorageState methods:

```
async saveStorageState(path: string) {
  if (this.context) {
    const storage = await this.context.storageState();
    await fs.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(storage));
  }
}

async setStorageState(path: string) {
  if (this.context) {
    const storageState = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(path, 'utf-8'));
    this.context = await this.browser.newContext({
      storageState, // Use the storageState here
      acceptDownloads: true,
      recordVideo: process.env.PWVIDEO ? { dir: 'screenshots' } : undefined,
      viewport: { width: 1200, height: 800 },
    });
  }
}
```

// And in Common-hooks in the "before" I will use the storageState

```
Before(async function (this: ICustomWorld, { pickle }: ITestCaseHookParameter) {
  this.startTime = new Date();
  this.testName = pickle.name.replace(/\W/g, '-');
  const storageState = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile('playwright/.auth/admin.json', 'utf-8'));
  this.context = await browser.newContext({
    storageState, // Use the storageState here
    acceptDownloads: true,
    recordVideo: process.env.PWVIDEO ? { dir: 'screenshots' } : undefined,
    viewport: { width: 1200, height: 800 },
  });
});
```

That is the right approach? because  I want to run later admin,teamlead und user storageState JSON in parallel. will this be defined in before hooks? if yes how to do it??

```
`const storageState = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile('playwright/.auth/teamlead.json', 'utf-`your text`8'));
const storageState = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile('playwright/.auth/admin.json', 'utf-8'));`
```

I want to use Playwright's and Cucumber's storageState to facilitate parallel login of different users (admin, team lead, user) in my test cases.

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple storage states, you can consider this approach.
In the feature file:

```js
@auth
Scenario Outline: Authenticated Users - Add to cart using admin

or

@auth
Scenario Outline: Authenticated Users - Add to cart using teamlead
```

In the common hooks:

```js
Before("@auth", async function (this: ICustomWorld, { pickle }) {
    context = await browser.newContext({
        storageState: getStorageState(pickle.name),
    });
    const page = await context.newPage();
    this.page = page;
});

async getStorageState(user: string) {
  if (user.endsWith('admin') {
    return JSON.parse(
      fs.readFileSync('path-to-storage-file/admin.json', 'utf8')
    )
  }
  if (user.endsWith('teamlead') {
    return JSON.parse(
      fs.readFileSync('path-to-storage-file/teamlead.json', 'utf8')
    )
  }
  return ''
}
```

It would be best to use a "page object model" to help structure the test suite.

I'm not sure about recreating the state file when the cookie expired, I'm still researching the best practice for it.

The idea comes from this video: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYUZujrURq0&list=PL699Xf-_ilW6KgK-S1l9ynOnBGiZl2Bsk&index=14&ab_channel=LetCodewithKoushik)